# Single/Double Click Handler for Swiftui Button

Tags: swiftui

I have not found a good answer to this (which seems like it should be trivial)-- I need to be able to recognise a single or double click on a Swiftui `Button` on a MacOS app, but the functionality does not appear to be native, and the workarounds with `.ongesture` and `.simultaneously`  always trigger the single click as well.
Or have I missed something?

Comment: I think you can accomplish this with TapGesture(count:) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tapgesture

Comment: Thanks... but that is not a native Button feature, and (as far as I can tell) will not solve the problem of having a handler that will react to either 1 or 2 clicks.
But I am not very deep into SwiftUI and could be wrong-- do you know of a working model? (The Apple Documentation link only works for one case).
It is a pity because I know that the clicks can be counted, and there must be an implementation somewhere for SwiftUI!

Answer (score 0):

As is so often the case, Paul Hudson at Hacking with Swift gave me some good hints. It is still not native to the Button struct (which I think it should be... something like .onDoubleClick or something like that). This is the simplest implementation I have been able to find:

```
struct hwsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("HWS")
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("Text single tapped")
                }
        }
        .highPriorityGesture(
            TapGesture(count: 2)
                .onEnded { _ in
                    print("hws double tapped")
                }
        )
    }
}
```